# Excel - Quickly Charting Frequency of Event To IP Address Over Time

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Warning: Keywords and tricky phrases may not be correctly being used here.  I'm not extremely knowlegable about the terms used with Microsoft Excel so I'm using my best guess.

I'm failing to find a simple means of creating a Scatter or Line chart in Excel given 3 columns: NumberMatches, DateOfMatch, and IP_AddressMatchedTo.  The goal is a Y axis of NumberOfMatches and X-Axis of Time mapped to DateOfMatch and each IP address has its own line to represent event changes over time.  The problem experienced is that I'm failing to find means of rapidly grouping each IP address to its own set of data.

Is there any way to logically group sets of data to a particular line in the chart so that the cumbersome task of grouping them is avoided?

[Here is a sample Excel file I'm working with.](https://app.box.com/s/kg86m1quc3gazs00q9l7)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the grouping your describing is assigning the data to a "series" which shares attributes on an Excel Chart. A quick way to do this is to use Excel's built-in Table functionality.

1. Convert your data to a Table `Insert > Table`
2. Use your Table to feed a Pivot Table `Insert > Pivot Table`
3. Set up your Pivot Table with:

   - Row Labels = Date
   - Column Labels = IP Address
   - Values = sum of Matches
4. Create a blank Scatter/XY Chart.
5. Add data, using the manual dialog box (it keeps Excel from getting too smart and messing things up). Each series will be named as the IP Address, X values will be your dates, and Y values will be the sum of Matches.
6. Format to taste.